# Join 2 data frame with special columns matching new

Tags: pandas

I want to join two dataframes and get result as below. I tried many ways, but it fails.

I want only texts on df2 ['A'] which contain text on df1 ['A']. What do I need to change in my code?

I want:

```
0  A0_link0
1  A1_link1
2  A2_link2
3  A3_link3
```

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
    })


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {        "A": ["A0_link0", "A1_link1", "A2_link2", "A3_link3", "A4_link4", 'An_linkn'],
             "B" : ["B0_link0", "B1_link1", "B2_link2", "B3_link3", "B4_link4", 'Bn_linkn']
    })
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, join= "inner", sort=False)
print(result)
```

Comment: You want `result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True, join= "inner", sort=False)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the index as `An` and `pd.concat` on columns

```py
result = (pd.concat([df1.set_index(df1['A']),
                     df2.set_index(df2['A'].str.split('_').str[0])],
                    axis=1, join="inner", sort=False)
          .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(result)

    A         A         B
0  A0  A0_link0  B0_link0
1  A1  A1_link1  B1_link1
2  A2  A2_link2  B2_link2
3  A3  A3_link3  B3_link3
```

Comment: i got error InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg) pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate dataframe and `map`:

```
d = (df2.assign(key=df2['A'].str.extract(r'([^_]+)'))
     .set_index('key'))

df1['A'].map(d['A'])
```

Output:

```
0    A0_link0
1    A1_link1
2    A2_link2
3    A3_link3
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Or `merge` if you want several columns from df2 (`df1.merge(d, left_on='A', right_index=True)`)

Comment: That’s exactly I wanted. But some time it can not run

Answer (score -1):

```
df2.A.loc[df2.A.str.split('_',expand=True).iloc[:,0].isin(df1.A)]

0    A0_link0
1    A1_link1
2    A2_link2
3    A3_link3
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  im from china my english is not very well ，so i cant explain it